# Selecting rows only if meeting criteria

Tags: postgresql

I am new to PostgreSQL and to database queries in general.

I have a list of user_id with university courses taken, date started and finished.
Some users have multiple entries and sometimes the start date or finish date (or both) are missing.

I need to retrieve the longest course taken by a user or, if start date is missing, the latest.
If multiple choices are still available, then pick random among the multiple options.

For example

- on user 2 (below) I want to get only "Economics and Politics" because it has the latest date;
- on user 6, only "Electrical and Electronics Engineering" because it is the longer course.

The query I did doesn't work (and I think I am off-track):

```
    (SELECT Q.user_id, min(Q.started_at) as Started_on, max(Q.ended_at) as Completed_on, 
q.field_of_study 
    FROM
    (select distinct(user_id),started_at, Ended_at, field_of_study
    from educations
    ) as Q
    group by Q.user_id, q.field_of_study )
    order by q.user_id
```

as the result is:

```
User_id   Started_on     Completed_on   Field_of_studies
   2      "2001-01-01"   ""             "International Economics"
   2      ""             "2002-01-01"   "Economics and Politics"
   3      "1992-01-01"   "1999-01-01"   "Economics, Management of ..."
   5      "2012-01-01"   "2016-01-01"   ""
   6      "2005-01-01"   "2009-01-01"   "Electrical and Electronics Engineering"
   6      "2011-01-01"   "2012-01-01"   "Finance, General"
   6      ""             ""             ""
   6      "2010-01-01"   "2012-01-01"   "Financial Mathematics"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this query should do what you need, it relies on calculating the difference in days between ended_at and started_at, and uses `0001-01-01` if the started_at is null (making it a really long interval):

```
select 
  educations.user_id,
  max(educations.started_at) started_at,
  max(educations.ended_at) ended_at, 
  max(educations.field_of_study) field_of_study
from educations
join (
  select 
  user_id, 
  max(    
    ended_at::date
    -
    coalesce(started_at, '0001-01-01')::date
  ) max_length
  from educations
  where (started_at is not null or ended_at is not null)
  group by user_id
) x on educations.user_id = x.user_id
   and ended_at::date
       -
       coalesce(started_at, '0001-01-01')::date
       = x.max_length
group by educations.user_id
;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!15/91028/2)

Comment: Thank you @jpw! your query works in most of the cases. however it doesn't prioritise the most recent between courses with same length. User 9 still shows 2 courses as they have same length: 9;"";"Katrinelund Gymnasium";"1993-01-01";"1996-01-01"
 - and - 9;"";"Birkbeck (University of London), UK";"2005-01-01";"2008-01-01"
In the above example I need to display only the one finished in 2008.

Comment: @Marcello I've updated my answer; it should now select the latest course, but if there are several courses with equal length and dates it should select the course with "highest" name (in a lexiographic order).

Comment: I have added  'distinct' to prevent duplication and it now works fully. thank you!